# Convert numbers to degrees in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm getting `25` from the API which must be converted to `-45` and the end result must be:

```
<div style="transform: rotate(-45deg);">
```

My current code looks like this:

```
<div style="transform: rotate({{data.angle}}deg);">
```

Basically, I need to convert

```
0   to -90
25  to -45
50  to   0
75  to  45
100 is  90
```

FYI, I'm creating a speedometer. You may see the HTML demo: https://jsfiddle.net/bcgzrdfL/

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: Start from zero an use a simple proportion to get your angle

Comment: Try `1.8*x - 90`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more of a mathematics problem than programming one. Linear equation `y = a*x + b` satisfies your transformation conditions. After solving it, given your inputs you'll get the following function:

```
toDegrees(input: number): number {
  return 1.8 * input - 90;
}
```

And the usage in the template:

```
<div style="transform: rotate({{toDegrees(data.angle)}}deg);">
```

Comment: I'm marking this as correct but I'm unable to use it in my scenario as the code changed. Could you kindly have a look at it? I'm stuck here as I have to use it in ngStyle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59061404/convert-number-to-degrees-in-ngstyle-using-angular-8