# Convert number to degrees in ngStyle using Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-style

{{result.percentage}} gives me a number from 0 to 100.

If I get 25, I want it to convert to -45 degrees or if I get 0, I want it to convert to -90 degrees or if I get 75, then it gets converted to 45 degrees.

```
[ngStyle]="{'transform': 'rotate(' + result.percentage + 'deg)'}"
```

Current, this gives an output `style="transform: rotate(25deg);"` which I want to convert to `style="transform: rotate(-45deg);"`

How do I go about this?

FYI, I need to bind the data of this speedometer: https://jsfiddle.net/bcgzrdfL/

Comment: what happens if its not one of those preset values?

Comment: The math should be able to handle this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need a math whiz, not a framework expert, however I'm going to take a shot at an answer:

```
[ngStyle]="{'transform': 'rotate(' + ((result.percentage * 1.8) - 90) + 'deg)'}"
```

Comment: Perfect!! I actually tried this but got stuck by missing a bracket. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

**html**

```html
[ngStyle]="{'transform': 'rotate(' + convertedPercentage + 'deg)'"
```

**component**

```js
get convertedPercentage() {
  return (this.result.percentage * 1.8) - 90;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have use the solution given by @Damian C.

Answer (score 1):

from a performance perspective, you're better off calculating the value only when it needs to be calculated, rather than doing the math in template.

```
styles = {}

setStyles(percentage) {
   this.styles = {
     'transform': 'rotate(' + ((percentage * 1.8) - 90) + 'deg)'
   }
}
```

call that when you get / assign your result or change your percentage, then use in template like:

```
[ngStyle]="styles"
```

the way you have it now, the degrees get calculated on every change detection cycle instead of only when they need to.  This is a bad practice that will lead to poor app performance if you keep doing it.